# CustomerAddresses is not defined -- editing customer addresses

Tags: javascript, customer-address

When editing the customer addresses in the backend of my magento installation, it gives me this JS error. I can't click the edit,delete or add button in the addresses page. I have checked the `addresses.php` file, but can't find the location of where `customerAddresses` is set. Is it a case of a missing library script?

(P.s. This is my first time working/troubleshooting Magento, i have been programming for a while though.)

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug until Magento 1.6.2.0 including. It was fixed in Magento 1.7.*

The file affected is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/addresses.phtml`

The fix for this bug is (taken from Magento 1.7.0.1 file):

```
// preventing duplication of ids for fields and blocks
while ($$("div[id='form_address_item_" + this.itemCount + "']").length) {
    this.itemCount++;
}
```

It happens only for the first ids of addresses because you can't have realistically too many addresses in a customer account.